# Need to remove a child using hit test object function

Tags: actionscript-3

i am trying to make a function where i drop some seeds into a bucket and the seeds are removed however the function will just be the seeds colliding with the bucket.

I have both of the objects as movieclips and have a basic hitTestObject conditional statement, i have no idea why the feed_mc wont be removed.

```
    if(bucket_mc.hitTestObject(feed_mc))
    {
    if(stage.contains(feed_mc))
    removeChild(feed_mc);
    }
```

thank you in advance

Sorry should have edited here

my code

```
   var Necessities:Array = new Array (Seed, shelter, water);

   for(var i:int = 0; i< 10; i++)
   {
   var pickObjects = Necessities[int(Math.random()* Necessities.length)];
   var Objects:MovieClip = new pickObjects();
   addChild(Objects);

   Objects.x = Math.random() + 600;
   Objects.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;

   }


   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, feedHen);


   function feedHen(e:Event):void {

   if(hen_mc.hitTestObject(Objects))

   {
    if (Objects.parent)
   Objects.parent.removeChild(Objects);
   }
   }
```

Comment: and `stage.contains(feed_mc)` is `true`? try `stage.removeChild(feed_mc)` if so

Comment: I have feed_mc on the stage so i guess it is true since the stage contains it. 

The stage.removeChild(feed_mc) did not work, still just passes over it

Comment: `trace(feed_mc.parent);` will show the parent `DisplayObjectContainer`.

Comment: so you need to remove your `Objects`?

Comment: could you please describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you execute that first code? What is `feed_mc`? Please post the code surrounding the first snippet that you posted.

Comment: I am making a game where you take care of a hen and in this particular instance you have to feed the hen by putting chicken feed into a bucket or trough so i need the chicken feed movieclip 'feed_mc' to be removed when it comes in contact with the bucket movieclip bucket_mc, one of the movie clips will be drag and droppable which i have working.

Sorry for the confusion

Comment: could you add a function where it happens to the question? If it is an event listener, add an `addEventListener` call where it is added

Comment: i believe i have added what you are looking for in the question, at the moment i am playing around with different ways to achieve my games goal and another idea is to have multiple of the objects and you bring the 2 seperate buckets to collect the certain items, i have only been able to make the bucket remove 1 random object, so i think i need a for loop statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like

```
if(feed_mc.parent){
    feed_mc.parent.removeChild(feed_mc);
}
```

should help - if you are not sure what `DisplayObjectContainer` is `parent`

**edit**
*I think this should work*

```
    var Necessities:Array = new Array (Seed, shelter, water);
    //store Objects here
    var objectsVector:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
    for(var i:int = 0; i< 10; i++){
        var pickObjects = Necessities[int(Math.random()* Necessities.length)];
        var Objects:MovieClip = new pickObjects();
        addChild(Objects);      
        objectsVector.push(Objects);//add to Vector
        Objects.x = Math.random() + 600;
        Objects.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    }

   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, feedHen);

    function feedHen(e:Event):void {
        for(var i: int = objectsVector.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){//loop through stored objects
            if(hen_mc.hitTestObject(objectsVector[i])){
                if (objectsVector[i].parent){
                    objectsVector[i].parent.removeChild(objectsVector[i]);
                    objectsVector.splice(i, 1);//remove from storage
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

However I'd suggest checking on some mouse events instead of `ENTER_FRAME` to reduce number of function calls

Comment: I have seem to make movie clips be deleted when added using actionscript 3 over having them on the stage before running the game. However it will only remove 1 specific movie clip, here is my code.

        var Necessities:Array = new Array (Seed, shelter, water);

        for(var i:int = 0; i< 10; i++)
        {
 var pickObjects = Necessities[int(Math.random()* Necessities.length)];
 var Objects:MovieClip = new pickObjects();
 addChild(Objects);
 
 Objects.x = Math.random() + 600;
 Objects.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
 
        }

Comment: i tried the code however some of my text gets deleted the objects seem to be spawning at the top and mostly off the screen as well as i get these errors.

TypeError: Error #1006: push is not a function.
 at littleredhen_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
 at littleredhen_fla::MainTimeline/gogo()

Comment: thank you so much, you are amazing!

If i were to add a var to count the objects being picked up would i code it outside this paragraph of code or would it be a seperate paragraph?

Comment: @vectorfox you are welcome) If you need a counter to be accessible outside (or in other words not only inside) the `function`/`for` loop, you should create it outside